# Not able to get content of <span> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've tried multiple approaches now, bit I'm not able to get it right.
I've got multiple list items and in a few of them I've got `<span class="required">*</span>`

I need to check if the `input.brand name` has value. If not, I will change the content of the span with a message.

To test, I've got the following code:

```
    jQuery('#brand_btn_saveForm').live('click', function() {
      alert(jQuery('#brand_name').parent().find('.required').text());
    });
```

This should output `*`, but I only get blank.

Part og the HTML code is this:

```
    <li>
    <label class="description" for="brand_name">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div>
        <input id="brand_name" name="brand_name" class="text textfield50pc" type="text" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/> 
    </div> 
    </li>
```

Any advice?

Comment: don't see anything in your html code with id of brand_email, not to mention within the span.required.

Comment: Sorry, typo. But they both got `require` span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `parent()` on the `<input>` returns the `<div>` while you want the `<li>` in order to be able to locate `<span class="required">`. You need `closest('li')` instead.

```
alert(jQuery('#brand_name').closest('li').find('.required').text());
```

As to the functional requirement, I'd suggest to take a look at [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation).

Comment: Ah! I should have seen that. Still not got the hang of all the functions. Thanks :)

Comment: One more thing. Why can't I use `closest` to find the `span`?

Comment: Because the `<input>` is not inside the `<span>`. The `closest()` finds the closest parent matching the given selector. http://api.jquery.com/closest/